# Loading a partial view in jQuery dialog MULTIPLE times

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-dialog

I'm using jQuery Dialog to create new Customers. The first time I open the dialog it calls the Controller Action method to create a new Customer model. Subsequent loads of the dialog DO NOT call the Action method, which isn't what I want.

Either I need to properly dispose the dialog on close, or force it to be recreated on load. Whatever I try doesn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 400,
            resizable: false,
            title: 'New Customer',
            modal: true,
            open: function(event, ui) {
                $(this).load("@Url.Action("CreateCustomerPartial")");
            },
            buttons: {
                "Close": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

        $('#my-button').click(function () {
            $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="dialog" title="Create Customer" style="overflow: hidden;">
```

Comment: What does `$(this).load("@Url.Action("CreateCustomerPartial")");` look like in the served page?

Comment: It determines the url path for the action method (MVC) - $(this).load("/MyApplication/MyController/MyAction");

Comment: From a client-side perspective the code looks OK. Try adding a 'complete' callback to check if/how the server responds - see the "Display a notice if the Ajax request encounters an error" in the documentation for [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Comment: I managed to figure it out. The issue is with IE caching, not jQuery Dialog. It can be disabled using $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

Answer (score 0):

Fixed - it was an issue with IE caching the ajax request, nothing to do with jQuery Dialog.

Disabling ajax caching did the trick:

`$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });`

Comment: `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false })` is a bit drastic as it will affect any other ajax requests elsewhere in your code, not just this one. I would recommend using the low level `$.ajax()`, which allows you to specify `cache:false` as an option. You will have to manage the insertion of the response into `$(this)` yourself but that's not hard.